# Silex/Symfony2 validator with dependancy injection

Tags: php, silex

OK so I want to make validator with DI on DBAL connection. I figure out sth like this:

**Constraint**

```
class UserExists extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Podany login "%string%" jest już zajęty.';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
       return 'validator.user.exists';
    }
}
```

**Validator**

```
public $conn;

public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    $sql = "SELECT count(1) AS liczba FROM uzytkownicy WHERE login= ? ";
    $exists = $this->conn->fetchAssoc($sql, array($value));  //this->conn is NULL

    if ($exists) {
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->setParameter('%string%', $value)
            ->addViolation();

            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public function setConn(Connection $conn)
{
    $this->conn = $conn;
}
```

**Provider**

```
class UserExistsProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
public function register(Application $app)
{   
    $app['validator.user.exists'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
        $validator =  new UserExistsValidator();
        $validator->setConn($app['db']);
        return $validator;
    });
}

public function boot(Application $app) {}
}
```

This is how i register my services:

```
$app->register(new UserExistsProvider());

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider(array(
'validator.validator_service_ids' => array(
    'validator.user.exists' => $app['validator.user.exists']
     )
)));
```

So when I var_dump $app['validator.user.exists'] it has correct initialized value for $conn property, though in my form validation route I have such an error:

> ClassNotFoundException in ConstraintValidatorFactory.php line 46:
>   Attempted to load class "validator.user.exists" from the global namespace.
>   Did you forget a "use" statement?

I mention about $conn property because when I comment validatedBy() method in my constraint I can initialize validation class, but the $conn property is empty.